# Why MouseEvent returns the same coordinates for getX() and getSceneX() in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have problems to understand how this work. If I make a circle in SceneBuilder 2.0 and  use this method:

```
circleLayer.setOnMousePressed(me -> {
    System.out.println("***" + me.getX() + " " + me.getY());
});
```

I get the values x and y relatives to the circle (the middle is 0,0). That is what I need. But if a do exactly the same in code, I get the scene coordinates.

The code:

```
public class Main2 extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    private Circle circleLayer;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        scene = new Scene(root, 600, 460);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        //
        circleLayer = new Circle(300, 300, 100);
        circleLayer.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
        root.getChildren().add(circleLayer);
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
        circleLayer.setOnMousePressed(me -> {
            System.out.println("***"+me.getX() +" "+me.getY());
        });
        //
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, mouseEvent ->{
            System.out.println(mouseEvent.getX()+" "+mouseEvent.getY());
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? Why I'm getting the same values with `getX()` and `getSceneY()`?

I need to get the coordinates relative to the `Circle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate system of a shape, if it has no transforms applied to it, will be the same as the coordinate system of its parent. In this case the parent is the root of the scene, so the coordinate system of the parent (and hence the of the circle) is the same as the coordinate system of the scene. Hence `getX()` and `getY()` for mouse events on the scene and on the circle produce the same result.

To get what you're trying to achieve (as far as I understand it), you want the circle to have center `(0,0)`:

```
circleLayer = new Circle(0, 0, 100);
```

and you can then move it to the location in the parent you want, while preserving its local coordinate system, using a translation:

```
circleLayer.setTranslateX(300);
circleLayer.setTranslateY(300);
```

I can't comment on the effect you're seeing with SceneBuilder, as you didn't post the code.